# transfer file from Mac/Pc to ios app documents without itunes

Tags: ios, itunes

I have an app that is using itunes file sharing.I use these file to get output. So users need to  use itunes to transfer file to app documents. I'd like to know how itunes do this transfer. So I can create client app for mac/pc.
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to solve your problem with [libimobiledevice](http://www.libimobiledevice.org/).
Open-Source and widely used.